# Asp.net mvc 5.1.0.0 and form authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using `Asp.net MVC 5.1.0.0` and I have an area by the name `Admin` I want to  use `Authentication form` in this area, so I added this

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Admin/Account/Login" defaultUrl="/Admin/General/Index" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20"></forms>
</authentication>
```

to the area's Web.Config file, but it gives me error

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

so I think it's not the way, there is any way to do `authentication` for admin area?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, forms authentication can only be configured at the application level. That means that you can only put the `<authentication>` tag in the ***root*** `web.config` file.

> is any way to do authentication for admin area?

If you only want to use authentication in the admin area, then you should only use the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) on classes and/or action methods inside of that one area. All other portions of the site will be accessible to everyone.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.98).aspx